# How can I close the whole Kotlin app when I click a button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I used exitProcess(1)
but it just goes back to the previous activity!
I want to close every activity when I click the button.

Comment: Use `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```